# Upload lower version number of app

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have client with  an app in the app store that was at version 4.05 and they accidentally submitted a new build as version 5.06 when they meant to submit it as 4.06. They aren't ready yet for a full version number increase. Long story.

Is it possible to submit the next version as 4.06 to get it back on track? Or is not allowed to upload a lower version to iTunes Connect?

Comment: was the version 5.06 accepted yet? If not, you should be able to reject the binary and reset.

Comment: @ChristianSchlensker did it work? were there any problems in review?

Comment: @ChristianSchlensker another question: do you need to set the version in your plist *and* on itunes connect or just itunes connect? thanks!

Comment: The issue I had was with the public facing version number. The one that shows up in the store. You fill this out in the itunes connect dialog where it says "Version Number:" and "What's New in this Version". It turns out that these numbers don't need to be sequential, only unique. They are used more for marketing purposes than for anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The version numbers only need be distinct.

From the Developer Guide:

> **A Version Number** The unique version
>   number of the app. Keep the following
>   in mind:
>
> - Use typical software versioning conventions (for example, “1.0 or
>     1.0.1 or
>     1.1”).
> - Do not include words such as “build” , “version” or “beta” in your version
>     number. This will appear next to your
>     application icon on the app product
>     page.